# bindActionCreators and mapDispatchToProps - Do I need them?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I'm looking at a React-Redux app and try to understand how everything is working.

Inside one of the components, I saw these lines of code:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";

...

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchPhotos }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(SearchBar);
```

If I change the above code to the following, everything still works, without any errors:

```
function mapStateToProps(photos) {
  return { photos };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { fetchPhotos }
)(SearchBar);
```

To me, it seems that my way of using connect is easier to understand and it also doesn't need to import an extra library.

Is there any reasons, to import **bindActionCreators** and use **mapDispatchToProps**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a Redux maintainer.

Yes, the second example you showed uses [the "object shorthand" form of `mapDispatch`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch#defining-mapdispatchtoprops-as-an-object).

**We recommend always using the “object shorthand” form of `mapDispatch`, unless you have a specific reason to customize the dispatching behavior.**

Comment: Sorry, but my point is that in my second example I don't use mapDispatchToProps at all. Instead I use mapStateToProps and I can still pass the action fetchPhotos to my component. Now my question is, why should I use mapDispatchToProps, when I can use mapStateToProps. Is there any reason why should I use mapDispatchToProps rather than mapStateToProps?

Comment: The second argument to `connect` is called `mapDispatchToProps`, and it's meant to let you define how your component can dispatch actions to the Redux store.  Passing an object is a valid form of "`mapDispatch`".  `mapStateToProps` is a totally different parameter, and is meant to let you define what data your component receives from the Redux store.  They're not the same thing.

Comment: Now I got it. When I pass { fetchPhotos } as an object, it is like using mapDispatchToProps. However, by passing the action fetchPhotos as an object, I don't need to write mapDispatchToProps any more. Right?

Comment: Basically, yes.

Answer (score 1):

I personally avoid using bindActionCreators explicitly. I prefer to directly dispatch the functions with mapDispatchToProps which internally uses bindActionCreators.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
 photos: state.photos.photos
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  fetchPhotos: () => dispatch(fetchPhotos())
  // ...Other actions from other files
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

There are two cases in which you'll use bindActionCreators explicitly, both are not best practices:

1. If you have a child component to SearchBar that does not connect to redux, but you want to pass down action dispatches as props to it, you can use bindActionCreators. 
   Best practice would be doing same with example I. You can just pass `this.props.fetchPhotos` to childcomponent directly without using bindActionCreators.

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
         <ChildComponentOfSearchBar fetchPhotos={this.props.fetchPhotos} />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
 photos: state.photos.photos
});

const mapDispatchToProps = () => bindActionCreators({ fetchPhotos }, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

2. There is another unlikely scenario where you can use bindActionCreators, defining actionCreator inside the component. This isn't maintainable & is not a good solution since action types are hard coded and not reusable.

```
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.fetchPhotosAction = bindActionCreators({ fetchPhotos: this.searchFunction }, dispatch);
  }

  searchFunction = (text) => {
   return {
     type: ‘SEARCH_ACTION’,
     text
   }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        // Importing selectively
        <ChildComponentOfSearchBar fetchPhotos={this.fetchPhotosAction} />
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
 photos: state.photos.photos
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(SearchBar)
```

Comment: Thanks. but what about mapDispatchToProps? When should I use it? Would it be ok if I always use mapStateToPprops?

Comment: mapDispatchToProps should be used when you are using something from action creators. If you are not going to dispatch any action that triggers global state change s, then you don't need mapDispatchToProps at all.

Comment: OK, I get it. But it seems that I could instead of mapDispatchToProps use mapStateToProps and it will work too. Why should I use mapDispatchToProps?

Comment: I think you are confused between stateToProps and dispatchToProps. 

To access the data/value stored in global-redux-store's state, we use mapStateToProps. 

To gets its action function for redux store to modify the global state, we use mapDispatchToProps..