# REDUX-REACT - dispatch undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, jsx

Dispatch in component is UNDEFINED and dispatch in mapDispatchToProps is ok

Action and reducers is ok - 100%;
I want transfer to dispatch in action to create request and run action from action

My component:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import  { carAction, fetchDogAction } from '../../../actions/CarAction';

class CarListContainer extends Component {
    render () {

        const { cars, carAction, dispatch, dog } = this.props;

        console.log(dispatch) // THIS UNDEFINED!!!!

        return(
            <Fragment>
                <Title onClick={() => {
                    fetchDogAction(dispatch)
                }}>HEllo</Title>

                {cars.map((elem) => 
                    <Title onClick={() => {carAction (elem)}} key={elem.id}>{elem.mark}</Title>
                )}

                {dog ? <img src={dog.message} /> : null }
            </Fragment>
        )
    }
}

const Title = styled('h2')`
    color: red;
    font-size: 30px;
`;

function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {
        cars: state.cars,
        dog: state.dog
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    console.log(dispatch) //THIS DISPATCH IS OK
    return bindActionCreators ({
        carAction: carAction,
        fetchDogAction: fetchDogAction
    }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CarListContainer);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error comes from having bindActionCreators() inside mapDispatchToProps() which is not recommended practice, since mapDispatchToProps uses bindActionCreators internally.

[bindActionCreators and mapDispatchToProps - Do I need them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55034527/bindactioncreators-and-mapdispatchtoprops-do-i-need-them)

You can try using an arrow function and dispatching actions directly in the mapDispatchToProps method.

```
import * ACTIONS from './actions'

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        carAction: (elem) => dispatch(ACTIONS.fetchCarAction(elem)) ,
        dogAction: () => dispatch(ACTIONS.fetchDogAction()) 
    }
}

//action creators import them into your component
export const fetchCarAction = (elem) => {
  return {
    type: ACTION_TYPES.CARACTION,
    payload: elem
  }
}

export const fetchDogAction = () => {
  return {
    type: ACTION_TYPES.DOGACTION,
  }
}

//render method

<Title onClick={() => this.props.dogAction() }>HEllo</Title>


{cars.map((elem) => 
  <Title onClick={() => this.props.carAction(elem) } key={elem.id}>{elem.mark} 
  </Title>
  )}
```

So in your render you will call the name of the property in mapDispatchToProps and not the name of the action creator, I kept the name of the action creators and name of the properties different so you can see this.

If you want a fully functioning react-redux app you can check out this starter project I built, I got good feedback on it.

https://github.com/iqbal125/modern-react-app-sample